# ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table is full

Tags: mysql, mariadb, errors

I am trying create a table using a cross join or Cartesian Product subquery that creates a table with a large number of rows, like at least 148 million rows.  I get this

> ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table is full.

I plan on filtering and querying the table later on, but how can I create this table?

Comment: Ensure you have enough disk space, may be?

Comment: I changed a couple of system global variables and now I can't connect to the database on Workbench or at the command line prompt. I think it was the max_heap_table_size variable that's messed things up.

Comment: Is the disk full?  Is the tmp dir separate from the root dir?  If so, it it full?  Don't set `max_heap_table_size` bigger than about 1% of RAM.  What other settings did you change?

Comment: I got the server backup and running.  whew!  I changed the system variable back to its original default.  I changed inno_db_file_path back to ibdata1:12M:autoextend instead of ibdata:512M:autoextend.  I am still curious on how to build a massive table.  I set max_heap_table_size to the maximum value allowed just to experiment.

Comment: I have 16 gb of ram (expandable to 32 gb) and a terabyte hard disk drive with 128 gb solid state drive.  My cpu is corei7.  I have pretty good specs, but I don't know if it's possible or my laptop.  I definitely don't want to output the Cartesian (Cross Join).  I do want to create the table with the cross join as a subquery, and then query and filter it.

Comment: using show variables,I found out the location of tmp dir:  C:\WINDOWS\SERVIC~2\NETWOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp

Comment: For some reason I can't raise the value in the innodb_db_file_path 
    ibdata12M:autoextend

Answer (score -2):

Check, if you did not run out of disk-space (this is the first step, check the tmp file)

From the comments, You seem to have a too low maximum size for your `innodb_data_file_path`, You cannot host more than 512MB of data in all innodb tables combined.

I think you should switch to an [innodb-per-table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html) scheme using `innodb_file_per_table`.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with tmp file, but I was able to change my datadir to my d drive.  I have 128 gb solid state drive, and a terabyte hard disk drive on my laptop.  Mysql workbench is stored on my c drive.  I think it has something to do with the settings of Mysql.

Comment: It is becoming clearer to me that I am going to have to pay to do more.  Mysql is open source after all.

Comment: **You cannot host more than 512MB of data in all innodb tables combined.** [you copy-pasted  and didn't cite your source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/730600/124486). That's just half the answer and that statement makes no sense without context.